# Add a section when a checkbox is checked through Flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, sales-cloud, experience-cloud, screen-flow

I have a requirement to create a **lightning flow** where I need to add a section containing fields  Name, description, and add on clicking of  Add checkbox (Refer Image_1).
Inthis section if a user checks on  Add checkbox field , then a new section should be created with same fields.(Refer Image_2)

**What I have done**

I have created a section that has Name, description, and Add checkbox Fields and set the visibility of the Section when (First Add ) is checked Refer Image_1.

From this Section if a user checks the checkbox named Add, so a new section should be added with Name, description and Add checkbox Field.

If a user repeats this process 10 times, I need to create a  different section 10 times and for each section give different API Name for fields as Name_1, Description_1, Name_2, Description_2 (Refer Image_2, Image3).

What is the better way to do this?

Image1:
[image: Image_1]

Image2:
[image: Image_2]

Image 3:
[image: Image_3]

Answer (score 0):

There is no better using native flow components using a single screen.

Flow doesn't have the ability to dynamically display UI elements based on an unknown sized list.  Even if you could create a collection of the records you want to create, displaying them isn't currently possible with native Flow elements.

i.e. the flow screen needs to already have the elements on it, and you specify the logic on each one when to display it.

If you need 10 sets of fields, you need to create then 10 sets of fields, then conditionally display them based on values in other fields.

There is a lot of complexity in here, so I'm not sure if this is really a good use of Flow.